# How can I troubleshoot Google Recaptcha validation issues with my PHP contact form?

Tags: php, validation, recaptcha, contact-form

I have a simple contact form that is not validating the Google captcha when submitting the form (email).

The form validates the Google captcha when the client fills in the form and ticks the captcha box but when you hit submit, it does not validate that captcha was successful (==true).

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Set your reCAPTCHA secret key
    $recaptcha_secret = "CAPTCHA_KEY_PLACEHOLDER";
    
    // Verify the reCAPTCHA response
    $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $recaptcha_data = array(
        'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
        'response' => $recaptcha_response
    );
    $recaptcha_options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($recaptcha_data)
        )
    );
    $recaptcha_context  = stream_context_create($recaptcha_options);
    $recaptcha_result = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url, false, $recaptcha_context);
    $recaptcha_json = json_decode($recaptcha_result);
    
    // Check if the reCAPTCHA verification was successful
    if ($recaptcha_json->success == true) {
        // Proceed with form submission
        if (isset($_POST['fullName']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject'])) {
            //Variables to read from HTML -> PHP
            $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['subject']; 

            //Reply messages
            $to = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_PLACEHOLDER";
            $subject = "Contact form submission from $fullName";
            $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

            //Conditional submit message
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                echo "<script>alert('Thank you! your message has been sent.');</script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Something has gone wrong, try again or refresh the page..');</script>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Display an error message and don't allow form submission
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter the reCaptcha verification before submission of forms.');</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: _"but when you hit submit, it does not validate that captcha was successful"_ - can you clarify what that actually means, please - does the email get send even if you did not complete the captcha, or what exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can var_dump($recaptcha_json); before check, to see exactly what's going on behind decoded data.

It should be provided with eventual error codes and descriptions.